# After using transform to rotate, UI view doesn't move to screen bounds

Tags: swift, rotation, resize

evening! I have an app that is only used in portrait, but I need to play a video in landscape in one controller. video plays in the videoView UIView.

in the story board the view is 5mm off the window bounds.
in order to try and achieve this, I rotate videoView, now the video plays in landscape, but the problem is it does not fill the screen, it seems to stay the width it was before rotted and squashes back to fit the screen widthways.

I need to make the UIview fill the screen after rotation... is it possible? I have tried everything I can think of in the storyboard and tried coding below to size after the rotation, but nothing seems to change the size of the UIView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            videoView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 45 * .pi/90.0)
            videoView.frame.size.height = view.frame.height
            videoView.frame.size.width = view.frame.width

    }
```

All suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
super.viewDidLoad()
viewVideo.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:CGFloat(M_PI_2))
viewVideo.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: iPhoneWidth, height: iPhoneHeight)   
}

where 
iPhoneWidth  =  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
iPhoneHeight =  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
```